# Azure Stream Analitics list in the list

Tags: azure, stream, azure-stream-analytics

How do I take the data from the file list if json array is in the list? eg.

```
   {"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji",
"coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},
"country":"JP",
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0045,
"cnt":38,
"list":[{
        "dt":1406106000,
        "main":{
            "temp":298.77,
            "temp_min":298.77,
            "temp_max":298.774,
            "pressure":1005.93,
            "sea_level":1018.18,
            "grnd_level":1005.93,
            "humidity":87
            "temp_kf":0.26},
        "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
        "clouds":{"all":88},
        "wind":{"speed":5.71,"deg":229.501},
        "sys":{"pod":"d"},
        "dt_txt":"2014-07-23 09:00:00"}
        ]}
```

How do I get to weather.main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your JSON format seem to have errors, let's fix these first:

```
{"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji"},
"coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},
"country":"JP",
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0045,
"cnt":38,
"list":[{
        "dt":1406106000,
        "main":{
            "temp":298.77,
            "temp_min":298.77,
            "temp_max":298.774,
            "pressure":1005.93,
            "sea_level":1018.18,
            "grnd_level":1005.93,
            "humidity":87,
            "temp_kf":0.26},
        "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
        "clouds":{"all":88},
        "wind":{"speed":5.71,"deg":229.501},
        "sys":{"pod":"d"},
        "dt_txt":"2014-07-23 09:00:00"}
        ]},
```

Note comma after at the end of humidity line, and closed record in the first line after Shuzenji.

Now, in the JSON example weather.main, is actually `list[0].weather[0].main`. Here is the way to get precisely this value
out of the JSON structure using [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt270219.aspx) and [Record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt270223.aspx) built-in functions:

```
SELECT
    -- input.list[0].weather[0].main
    WeatherMain = GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(input.list, 0), 'weather'), 0), 'main')
FROM input
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.